# How to write the hibernate hbm file for this relation

Tags: hibernate

I have a user table and a user_detail table with one to one mapping user_detail table have a field user_id to be used for this relation which stores id field value of corresponding user.  How to write the hibernate hbm file for this relation?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: 100's of links can be available for the One TO One Mapping, please post when you are getting some error or stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@Vipin,
       Refer the below link to learn it :) :

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-xml-mapping/